# How to connect user to different Cloud SQL instance once they login?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We got one GCP project contains 3 Cloud SQL instance and each one in a different GCP region for a different group of users.

What we would like is when the user login, I need to connect them to differnt instance based on a master table (another master SQL instance)?

Is that the best way to do, or we can do it differently?

Our application resides on Google app engine with Python flex env.

Thanks in advance!

Thinking about using the app engine custom domain mapping to point connect the user to different SQL instance by using different URL.

Answer (score 2):

For App Engine Flexible, you can configure the Cloud SQL Proxy to support more than one Cloud SQL instance. Just use different port numbers for each SQL instance when setting up the proxy. If you are using unix sockets, just specify the instance names.

For example:

unix sockets:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql \
-instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance,myProject:us-central1:myInstance2
```

Your connection string includes:

```
/cloudsql/myProject:us-central1:myInstance2
```

tcp:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy \
-instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:3306,myProject:us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:3307
```

The tcp method, specify the host as 127.0.0.1 and port (3306 or 3307).

Comment: Thanks, John, by defined all the SQL instance in cloud_sql_proxy, then how to redirect the user to the right SQL instance?

Comment: By using the correct connection string. You cannot redirect SQL instance connections. Close one and open another one.